# HBase : HFile stats not changed after flush

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I have a HBase table `'emp'`. I created some rows in it using `hbase-shell`, among which the biggest rowkey is `123456789`.
When I check on `HBase UI` (the web console) following the below path :

```
regions -> emp,,1582232348771.4f2d545621630d98353802540fbf8b00. -> hdfs://namenode:9000/hbase/data/default/emp/4f2d545621630d98353802540fbf8b00/personal data/15a04db0d3a44d2ca7e12ab05684c876 (store file)
```

I can see `Key of biggest row: 123456789`, so everything is good.

But the problem came when I deleted the row containing the rowkey `123456789` using `hbase-shell`. I also put some other rows, then finally flush the table `flush 'emp'`.

I see a second HFile generated. But the `Key of biggest row` of the first HFile is always `123456789`.

So I am very confused : this row no longer exist in my hbase table, and I already did a flush (so everything in memstore should be in HFile). Why in `stats` it always shows this rowkey ? What is going on behind the scene ?
And how can I update the `stats` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct in that everything in the memstore is now in HFiles, but until a compaction takes place the deleted row will still exist, albeit marked for deletion in the new, second HFile.

If you force a compaction with `major_compact ‘table_name’, ‘col_fam’`, you should see this record disappear (and be left with one HFile). Maybe there's a small bug in `stats` that doesn't take deleted records into account?

Comment: Hi, yes I think it's the reason. Do you know where the data in stats come from ? Is it from META table or from Zookeeper ?

Comment: I presume META, but if I get bored this weekend I'll take a deeper look and let you know.

Comment: Ok thank you! Now I just run the major_compact on my table, now the store file is of size 0 so I assume that it's good (no stats available any more). But the region with this startKey '123456789' is still there... so I have to delete the region in META table manually ?

Comment: The region will remain even though it's empty - if you add any future records to HBase then records with a key >= 123456789 will be inserted into that region.

Comment: Ok, so I suppose even I delete the region there will be no danger ?

Comment: I don't want to suggest anything that ruins your cluster, and honestly this isn't something I've done before. Looks like others have asked this question, albeit a long time ago https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6407531/hbase-how-to-delete-region.